# How to I add a custom variable defined in settings file that gets passed to each template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Something similar to the STATIC_URL, which gets defined in the settings.py file and is accessible in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) are for.